# Outlook Office context saveasync callback problem for new appointment

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have created a outlook addin which opens in create new appointment page. Here i am opening new appointment page and calling the below function to sync content appointment page.When i open appointment page for first time i am not getting any callback from saveasync method. it is taking so much time. If i close and open my app again and do the same then i am getting callback.

```
Office.context.mailbox.subject.setAsync('subject');
Office.context.mailbox.body.setAsync('sample body');
Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync(
function callback(result) {
   // Process the result.
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should nest your calls since they are all async.

```
Office.context.mailbox.subject.setAsync
(
    "subject",
    function (asyncResult0)
    {
        if (asyncResult0.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded)
        {
            Office.context.mailbox.body.setAsync
            (
                "sample body",
                function (asyncResult1)
                {
                    if (asyncResult1.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded)
                    {
                        Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync
                        (
                            function (result)
                            {
                                // Process the result
                            }
                        );
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }
);
```